# rails 6 package.json deploy problem "Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0"

Tags: deployment, package.json, production-environment, webpacker, ruby-on-rails-6

My `cap deploy` to  Rails production environments fails with the following yarn error `Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0` and it makes absolutely no sense to me. Below is that yarn error log snippet and below that the package.json causing the error:

yarn error log:

```
PATH:
  /home/deploy/synapse/shared/bundle/ruby/2.5.0/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.5.5/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/libexec:/home/deploy/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

Yarn version:
  1.19.2

Node version:
  8.16.2

Platform:
  linux x64

Trace:
  SyntaxError: /home/deploy/[APPNAME]/releases/20191210180716/package.json: Unexpected token v in JSON at position 0
      at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
      at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:1625:59
      at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
      at step (/usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:304:30)
      at /usr/share/yarn/lib/cli.js:315:13
      at <anonymous>
```

package.json

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@rails/webpacker": "4.2.2",
    "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "serialize-javascript": "^2.1.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.9.0"
  },
  "license": "UNLICENSED"
}
```

This fails deploying to production at `asset:precompile` but locally with RAILS_ENV=production precompile finishes without a hitch. so, what am I doing wrong here?

**EDIT**
 OK, when I look on the production machine package.json looks like this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:4289b53b39c2c47dd-other-digest-crap-beb0aefed39c39fa84e3b41f72056982
size 226
```

What?! Turns out this is an artifact of using git-lfs blanketly for all json files. See below.

Answer (score 0):

### Temporary fix

Ok, so to fix this, I explicitly linked package.json in from shared in my Capistrano deploy.rb

```rb
append :linked_files, "package.json" # depending on your religion you may also include "package-lock.json"
```

scp files to apps shared folder et voilà, ca suffit.

### Better Fix

OK, so the reason this problem exists at all is because I was blindly using git-lfs for all json files.  This particular application has a lot of json data.  Tracking `*.json` just isn't smart, especially for small files needed by rails, etc.  But there are 2 potential solutions to this:

1. I didn't have git-lfs install on my vps, installing solves the problem -- sort of. The problem is still that I probably don't want every single json file track by lfs just big json datafiles
2. I moved large json files to a single directory under `./data/` and `git lfs track "data/*"`

This seemed to fix the problem